# iOS : Send Multiple Apple Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

thanks in advance to those who will help

when I send a push notification to a single device i use this methodology

```
<?php


  $deviceToken = $_POST['TOKEN'];
  $message = $_POST['MESSAGGIO'];

  $badge = 0;
  $sound = "default";

  $body = array();
  $body['aps'] = array("alert" => $message);


  if ($badge)
        $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
  if ($sound)
        $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

  $ctx = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "local_cert", "apns-dev.pem");

  $fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

  if (!$fp) {
       echo json_encode("errore");
       return;
  } 

  $payload = json_encode($body);

  $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack("H*", str_replace(" ", "", $deviceToken)) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;

  fwrite($fp, $msg);

  fclose($fp);


?>
```

while when I have to send a notification to all the devices in my database (using the device token of course), I would have thought of doing so

```
<?php

  $deviceToken = $_POST['TOKEN'];
  $message = $_POST['MESSAGGIO'];

  $badge = 0;
  $sound = "default";

  $body = array();
  $body['aps'] = array("alert" => $message);


  if ($badge)
        $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
  if ($sound)
        $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

  $ctx = stream_context_create();
  stream_context_set_option($ctx, "ssl", "local_cert", "apns-dev.pem");

  $fp = stream_socket_client("ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195", $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);

  if (!$fp) {
   echo json_encode("errore");
   return;
  } 

  $payload = json_encode($body);

  //****

  $db = new PDO('sqlite:my_db.sqlite');

  $query = "SELECT device_token FROM user";
  $result = $db->query($query);

  foreach($result as $row){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack("H*", str_replace(" ", "", $row['device_token'])) . pack("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
  }

  //****

  fclose($fp);

?>
```

is a correct solution according to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct. You are using the same connection to send all the messages, which is the most important thing when sending multiple notifications.

However, you are using the simple binary format, which has no support for error responses, and therefore you have no error handling. This will work assuming your message never exceeds the max payload length and all the device tokens in your DB are valid. A better approach would be to use the enhanced binary format and read (and handle) error responses.

Comment: all device_token in the DB are 100% correct, because they are automatically added from the app itself 
the messages aren't long more than 60 characters, upstream of the call of the file that send the message there is this characters's control 

how could I do to read any error in sending the notification? 

thanks

Comment: @NicolòMonili Here's [sample code](http://learn-php-by-example.blogspot.com.es/2013/01/working-with-apple-push-notification.html) for sending push notifications with reading of error responses.